# HtmlService Form - Dynamic DropdownList

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a HtmlService Form that takes data from user.

There are multiple `dropdownlist` in the form.

Is it possible to eliminate a selection from subsequent `dropdownlist`, if user has already selected it in the first `dropdownlist`? Will `google.script.run` be able to do that?

Comment: This has little to do with GAS and more to do with JavaScript. Look around for questions about removing or adding elements to a website via JavaScript when a user clicks on something or selects something. There should be a few hundred very specific answers.

Comment: However, with the limitations in IFRAME sandbox of HtmlService, i'm not sure if it can be done

Comment: It most definitely can. I have fully featured singe page web apps utilizing AngularJS that are created with GAS. You can write your own JS, and reference 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Is this a good UI choice? What you are describing is the ability to select up to _n_ choices from a predetermined list. A more straightforward approach might be to have these options as checkboxes and limit (using JavaScript) how many can be checked. How many options are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for can be done with JavaScript right on the webpage, there is no need to make any calls back to the server with `google.script.run`. Here is an example JSfiddle of where you can click on a dropdown list and show a new portion of a site using JQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/rorfw6mb/1/

This should show you a basic way in which you can show different elements on the page based on the users selection.

```js
var optionsTemplates = { 
  'Option 1': '<span>Option 1 selected</span>',
  'Option 2': '<span>Option 2 selected</span>',
  'Option 3': '<span>Option 3 selected</span>',
  'Option 4': '<span>Option 4 selected</span>'
};

$('select').on('change', function(){
  let value = $(this).val();
  console.log(value);
  if(value !== ''){
    $('#option-container').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#option-container').html(optionsTemplates[value]);
  } else {
   $('#option-container').addClass('hidden');
  }
})
```

```css
#option-container.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#option-container {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: auto;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<div id="option-container" class="hidden">
  
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may lead to the OPs desired result, it's only tangentially related. i.e. Responding to a Select box change. Just my opinion, but this could be confusing to some (copy-pasters). Better to quickly hash up an actual mock of what's required or even pseudo code.

Comment: @Jonathon the goal was to provide OP with a very basic view of how to use templates to dynamically display elements on the page. It shouldn't be too difficult to scale up the templates to encompass larger portions of a form. If need be, OP could always find a proper HTML templating solution like handlebars, mustache, or go full in and start playing with angular.

Comment: The question is about editing the content of one node (or nodes) by the actions on another, specifically selection an option, not templating.

Comment: @Jonathon I see what you mean, that's a bit different, if all you have is a hammer then everything looks like a nail...etc. I'll go ahead and edit my answer appropriately when I am back home with a solution more in line with OP's request. Think it would be fine to keep what I currently have in the post, if that doesn't make it too long?

Comment: Don't sweat it, you've already provided more code than the OP as it is. Relax ;) I've commented above that the UI choice they are making seems wrong in any case. My comment was more for future googlers benefit.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help rendered. I'll keep in mind of the advice given.